# jax-ws change Content-type to Content-Type because server is hyper sensitive

Tags: java, http, header, client, jax-ws

I have to connect to a poorly implemented server that only understands `Content-Type` (capital-T) and not `Content-type`. How can I ask my JAX-WS client to send `Content-Type`?

I've tried:

```
Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>)
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
```

But `headers` is `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I have to connect to a poorly implemented server that only understands Content-Type(capital-T) and not Content-type. How can I ask my jax-ws client to send Content-Type?

I've dug this question a bit more and, sadly, I'm afraid the answer is: you can't. Let me share my findings.

First, the code that you'll find in https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/guide/HTTP_headers.html **does not** give you access to the HTTP headers of the future HTTP request (that hasn't been created at this point), it allows you to set **additional HTTP headers for making a request** (that will be added to the HTTP request later).

So, don't expect the following code to not return `null` if you don't `put` anything before (and actually, you'll only get what you `put` in there):

```
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
```

Then, I did a little test based on the code provided in the same link:

```
AddNumbersImplService service = new AddNumbersImplService();
AddNumbersImpl port = service.getAddNumbersImplPort();

((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,
    Collections.singletonMap("X-Client-Version",Collections.singletonList("1.0-RC")));

port.addNumbers(3, 5);
```

And this is what I see in the HTTP request when running the client code:

```
POST /q2372336/addnumbers HTTP/1.1
Content-type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"
X-client-version: 1.0-RC
Soapaction: ""
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
User-Agent: JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 249
```

Do you notice the difference: only the first char of the `X-Client-Version` header is kept upper cased, the rest is lowered!

And indeed, if you check the class [`c.s.x.w.t.Headers`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.1/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/Headers.java#Headers.normalize%28java.lang.String%29) that is used to represent HTTP request (and response) headers, you'll see that it "normalizes" keys when they are added (in `normalize(String)`):

```
/* Normalize the key by converting to following form.
 * First char upper case, rest lower case.
 * key is presumed to be ASCII 
 */
 private String normalize (String key) {
     ...
 }
```

So, while the [`c.s.x.w.t.h.c.HttpTransportPipe`](http://fisheye5.cenqua.com/browse/jax-ws-sources/jaxws-ri/rt/src/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/client/HttpTransportPipe.java?r=1.18) class (my understanding is that this is where the HTTP request is created, this is also where previously added headers will be added to the HTTP request headers) actually adds **`"Content-Type"`** as key in a [`c.s.x.w.t.Headers`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.1/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/Headers.java#Headers.normalize%28java.lang.String%29) instance, the key will be modified because of the previously mentioned implementation detail.

I may be wrong but I don't see how this could be changed without patching the code. And the odd part is that I don't think that this "normalizing" stuff is really RFCs compliant (didn't check what RFCs say about headers case though). I'm surprised. Actually, you should [raise an issue](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectIssues).

So I see three options here (since waiting for a fix might not be an option):

- Patch the code yourself and rebuild JAX-WS RI (with all the drawbacks of this approach).
- Try another JAX-WS implementation like CFX for your client.
- Let the request go through some kind of custom proxy to modify the header on the fly.

Comment: I've used the custom proxy for now... Ugly as hell and would like to remove this ugly mofo from my code. Oh well. C'est la via

Comment: @EsbenP If you raise an issue for this, please update the question with the link. I'd really like to get some feedback from JAX-WS RI developers on this.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the HTTP headers from the RequestContext. If you have access to the port object you can cast it to a javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider, which will give you access to the RequestContext.

You might also want to remove the unaccepted "Content-type" header.

This page shows how to do it in a bit more detail: https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/guide/HTTP_headers.html

Let me know if you need more code samples, or if you paste some of your code I can show you how to modify it.

Comment: the link is broken, also I tried msg.getMimeHeaders() then removeHeader or addHeader even removeAllHeaders nothing works, the vector backs the headers seems immutable