# How do I add HTTP headers to JAXWS created proxy classes

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, wsimport

I've created a set of proxy classes in NetBeans for a SOAP web service.

I'd like to add an HTTP header to the outgoing request.

```
Map<String, Object> requestHeaders = new HashMap<>();
requestHeaders.put("X-Header", header);
AccountManagementService service = new AccountManagementService();
AccountManagementServiceSoap soap = service.getAccountManagementServiceSoap();
GetMembershipSummaryResponse.GetMembershipSummaryResult membershipSummary = soap.getMembershipSummary("mikeb@foobar.com");
```

I saw a bunch of JAX-WS header examples for when you are getting the individual port from the service. Is there an easier way?  Can I just add the header to some collection on service or soap object?

Answer (score 0):

after some digging I found this post: [jax-ws change Content-type to Content-Type because server is hyper sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372336/jax-ws-change-content-type-to-content-type-because-server-is-hyper-sensitive)

which isn't really a full answer, so I am going to post the full answer here:

```
   AccountManagementService service = new AccountManagementService();
   AccountManagementServiceSoap soap = service.getAccountManagementServiceSoap();

   ((BindingProvider)soap).getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,
    Collections.singletonMap("X-Header",Collections.singletonList(header)));
   GetMembershipSummaryResponse.GetMembershipSummaryResult membershipSummary = soap.getMembershipSummary("mikeb@foobar.com");
```